# KeychainItemWrapper does not store credentials when app terminates

Tags: ios, keychain

I am attempting to use KeychainItemWrapper to store a username/password.

The credentials are kept if I send the application to background and everything.

But whenever I terminate the app (killing it in the multi tasking bar), when I start the app again, the values I previously stored are gone.

Here is how I am using it:

```
-(void) viewDidload{
    ...
    keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:KEYCHAIN accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItem setObject:@"MyAppString" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
}


-(void) login{
    ...
    [keychainItem setObject:usernameTextField.text forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecAttrAccount];
    [keychainItem setObject:passwordTextField.text forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecValueData];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've created another class for Login Check and calling the following methods of it.

-(id)init
{
    self    =   [super init];

```
if (self) {
keychainItem   =   [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"Login" accessGroup:nil];

    username    =   [[NSString alloc]init];
    password    =   [[NSString alloc]init];

}
return self;
```

}

-(BOOL)isFirstTimeLogin
{

```
password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

```
if([password isEqualToString:@""] && [username isEqualToString:@""])
{
    return TRUE;
}

else
    return FALSE;
```

}

-(void)setUsername:(NSString*)userName Password:(NSString*)passWord
{

```
[keychainItem setObject:passWord forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
[keychainItem setObject:userName forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

}
-(BOOL)verifyUsename:(NSString*)userName Password:(NSString*)passWord
{

```
password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

if([password isEqualToString:passWord] && [username isEqualToString:userName])
{
    return TRUE;
}

else
    return FALSE;
```

}